# How do you use q (querystring) and z (zoom) when trying to zoom in on a Google maps (using JavaScript) on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-mobile

I have written a media query in JavaScript that allows you to zoom (z) in on google maps mobile. I have also written a querystring (q) that allows you to enter an address or postcode. Both work when used individually. However, now I want to zoom (z) in on a given querystring (q) on Google maps (mobile devices), is this possible? And if it is how would I write the code for this?

Comment: Please show your individual examples.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code you have tried so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: something like this (https://www.google.com/maps/place//@46.090271,6.657248,16z)        but with a querystring that allows you to enter place/city AND will work on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, you cannot just give a `q` and `z` to the Google Maps, you also need the query `ll`, which stand for Latitude and Longitude of the center of the map, in order for the `zoom` to work with the `querystring`. Also look at this example:

https://www.google.com/maps?q=googleplex,+mountain+view,+ca&ll=37.4219999,-122.0840575&z=10

You can use the [geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to get the lat/lng of your location, or you can center your map to a general area you are targeting.

Comment: I like this answer - how would I generate a URL like this if I know the location (have it in the query string) and want to make it a fixed zoom when the URL is accessed (say like z=9)? And will this work on mobile devices (especially ipads and iphones)?